# Client not recognizing multiple textures for bake

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, baking

I'm currently working on a model that has two separate Materials. One for her clothes, and the other for her skin and hair. Unfortunately the platform I'm trying to upload her to only allows me to use one .PNG file so naturally I'm attempting to Bake them together. The two materials are the following.

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately Blender seems to only acknowledge one of them, despite the fact that both materials are currently applied to the mesh. Some of the Materials will no longer even show up in the preview, so half of materials in the window are just empty. When the Bake completes the single texture is then skewed across the mesh with the final baked texture looking like this.

[image]

Even though the both textures have been applied to the model as you can see here. It's as if it's both acknowledging the materials in the client while simultaneously ignoring it in almost every other window. Even when I load up a new model, it immediately renders her with both materials.
[image]

I've been at this from 9am til 1am the next day and no matter what I do, or which video I watch the results are always the same. I'm trying to get this model done by thursday for a big tabletop group going on so any help would be a life-saver to this poor girl, I have discord too if that makes explaining it any easier. Vuux#8268